# Marcar resposta correta por consenso

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado, moderação, resposta-aceita

Queria deixar a proposta de que moderadores e usuários bem pontuados possam marcar respostas esquecidas como corretas, isso seria feito somente depois de um prazo sem que uma determinada pergunta não seja avaliada como tendo uma resposta válida.

Não é um caso recorrente aqui, mas acontece, no site da [Communidade ARM](http://community.arm.com/) tem autonomia para selecionar uma determinada resposta como correta, porém lá o tema é específico, e os moderadores são engenheiros especializados em cada seção do site.

Comment: -1 Não concordo. Só o AP pode saber se a resposta é certa ou não. Eu tenho algumas perguntas sem resposta marcada como certa por achar que nenhuma resposta responde completamente a questão.

Comment: +1 Concordo. Dependendo da pergunta é possível que outras pessoas saibam se a resposta é certa ou não, principalmente nos casos em que o AP abandona a pergunta e só tem uma única resposta para ele (e certa, obviamente).

Comment: A meu ver o colocar o visto na resposta quer dizer "esta resposta resolveu o meu problema" não me parece lógico que outrem faça isso pelo AP.

Comment: @Math mas quem vai decidir esse "dependendo da pergunta"? Quem vai decidir se é certa ou não? E se os moderadores e utilizadores bem pontuados não estiverem de acordo?

Comment: @JorgeB. O problema é quando o AP não entende como funciona a comunidade, deixa um comentário do tipo "obrigado, resolveu meu problema" e abandona o tópico sem aceitar a resposta.

Comment: @JorgeB. poderia ter uma fila de análise, igual temos para fechar perguntas, primeiras publicações, etc.. Poderíamos ter uma fila de aceitação de respostas antigas onde o AP abandonou a comunidade, algo assim.

Comment: Ah isso é uma situação diferente da mencionada, isso é colocar o visto pelo AP. E mesmo assim não sei se concordo...

Comment: +1 Concordo e - 1 Não concordo. Há casos em que realmente só o autor pode saber a resposta certa e outros em que nenhuma das respostas seja a correta. Mas também há casos, como disse o Math, de haver uma resposta certa e o autor abandonar

Comment: Nem acho que isso seja o mais importante. É bom ter reconhecimento pelas nossas respostas, mas o principal é que as respostas estejam lá. E pela pontuação vê-se qual a melhor resposta. No SOen raramente olho para a resposta que têm visto sem primeiro verificar antes se tem uma com melhor pontuação.

Comment: Eu concordo com todas as colocações, muitas vezes os moderadores não saberão exatamente qual melhor resposta, segundo deveria haver uma sinalização de resposta mais bem pontuada, diferenciando também da resposta escolhida como certa. No caso do consenso, seria interessante pelo menos haver uma indicação "CONSENSUALMENTE CERTA" através de um icone, diferenciando o fato de ter sido indicada ou não pelo AP.

Comment: Este debate é bem antigo. Eu discordo da decisão tomada sobre isso pela SE (e talvez possamos tentar convencê-los a mudar de ideia), mas aqui está o link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature

Comment: @VictorStafusa, antes veja meu comentário anterior.
Também concordo que não se tenha que ter uma resposta certa, há casos que há mais de uma, e ambas inclusive com excelente pontuação, percebo que há diversos fatores que influenciam nisso inclusive o acaso.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/community-vote-for-accepted-answer-rep-5000-only - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80319/vote-to-force-accept-an-answer-for-someone-elses-question

Comment: A pontuação no caso deve ser considerada dentro das TAGs relativas a Questão sem resposta aceita.

Comment: @VictorStafusa e se eu deixar uma pergunta sem resposta propositadamente? Vão escolher uma por mim? Que lógica é essa?

Comment: Espero sinceramente que isto nunca ande para a frente.

Comment: @JorgeB. esta certo quanto uma resposta não satisfaz manter a pergunta em aberta, mas tem casos onde o AP simplesmente abandona a pergunta, mesmo após um ultimo comentário indicar uma solução e o AP não responde mais, nesses casos a pergunta deveria ficar suspensa ou analise para eleger uma resposta até que o AP respondesse alguma coisa a respeito do ultimo comentário ou resposta

Comment: um exemplo, eu respondi a pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72252/d%C3%BAvidas-sobre-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-assincrona-javascript/72412#72412 faz 2 dias que o AP não se manifesta se a resposta solucionou, a pergunta fica ali aberta, respondida e aguardando o AP falar alguma coisa, não teria problema nenhum deixar esse pergunta aberta se o ultimo a dar noticias fosse o próprio AP dando algum sinal negativo a respeito da ultima proposta oferecida, acho que teríamos que colocar um prazo para o AP se manifestar, depois desse prazo, suspender a pergunta por falta de retorno no minimo

Comment: .... ou eleger uma possível solução, uma vez que o AP abandonou a pergunta, claro que teríamos que estipular um prazo e esse deve ser algo mais justo acima dos 3 dias ao meu ver

Comment: @SneepSNinjA não concordo com nada disso, nem sequer isso é política do site. E ainda bem... Senão fugia tudo daqui e iam para um fórum comum...

Comment: JorgeB. na resposta abaixo do @LucasMotta, você diz que nenhum outro além do AP pode marcar a resposta como certa, porém há resposta marcadas como certas que são erradas, ou pelo menos inadequadas ao ambiente questionado, e estão marcadas pelo AP como certa, e este sequer retorna ao site para analisar a outra resposta, assim induzindo a outros a mais confusão.

Comment: @Delfino até pode induzir mas está no direito dele de induzir as pessoas em erro.

Comment: Por isso é que temos os downvotes e upvotes.

Comment: Concordo @JorgeB. é um direito, porém também é um direito que o consenso prevaleça e que se elimine tal ato em favor do crescimento da qualidade do site.

Comment: A escolha de respostas **também** por consenso não excluindo outros métodos contribui para que os que respondem realmente correto sejam mais valorizados do que os que simplesmente satisfazem a ansiedade de uma solução do AP.

Comment: Não concordo com isso @Delfino.

Comment: Empate.  :)
Poderia me convencer? :)

Comment: @Delfino esta resposta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4102/7210 diz tudo sem sequer entrar na temática que falei...

Comment: Bem, ainda acho válido ter um destaque diferenciado a resposta que tenham sido tomadas como certas por consenso. Além de sua pontuação.

Comment: A questão é muito interessante mas acho que para tal é preciso uma equipe de especialistas em todos os assuntos técnicos abordados no SO. Acho que aqui não tem estrutura suficiente para lidar com isso.

Comment: Uma pergunta de exemplo que está com cara que vai ter uma boa resposta com excelente pontuação e corre o risco de não ser marcada como a resposta certa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71973/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-getclass-getresourceasstream-e-getclass-getclassloader

Comment: Uma das vantagens de se acrescentar o método do consenso para destacar respostas é que elimina totalmente a sensação de abandono nas perguntas.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não estou dizendo que outros usuários deveriam escolher qual é a resposta correta porque o autor da pergunta se absteve. Não é nada disso! O que estou dizendo é que APENAS nos casos aonde o autor CLARAMENTE e INEQUIVOCADAMENTE deixou claro que uma dada resposta o satisfaz (por exemplo, com um comentário do tipo "valeu, funcionou perfeitamente, resolveu o meu problema", mas sem aceitar a resposta) é que talvez isso deveria ser feito. Além disso, veja a minha resposta abaixo, NÃO É ISSO que estou propondo.

Comment: @VictorStafusa "CLARAMENTE e INEQUIVOCAMENTE" não dá para garantir nunca ou quase nunca.

Comment: @VictorStafusa e não te esqueças que existindo esse mecanismo, iriam existir muitas respostas onde a aceitação ia ser votada e esse "CLARAMENTE e INEQUIVOCAMENTE" deixaria de existir. Tenho a certeza absoluta disso. Por meia dúzia de casos que acontecem vale a pena estragar o método de aceitação livre do AP? Vê este comentário http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4097/o-que-ganha-a-comunidade-em-ter-uma-resposta-aceite-em-cada-pergunta/4103?noredirect=1#comment11350_4103 que diz tudo...

Comment: Para mim, perguntas com mais de 15 dias sem melhor resposta deveriam ter a melhor resposta marcada automaticamente com base na postagem de maior pontuação..

Comment: O problema é que isso é muito subjetivo. Eu mesmo respondi perguntas que nunca tiveram um feedback do AP, e nem terá. Mas o que importa é que a resposta está lá para todos. Acho válida essa medida para o caso que o @Math colocou: O Ap se manifesta pelos comments.

Comment: Eu não li todos os comentários, mas podem também existir casos em que a pergunta não seja um problema, mas uma dúvida em que o autor da pergunta realmente não sabe se a resposta é certa, por exemplo, fiz hoje [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75904/posso-vender-um-subproduto-de-um-produto-sob-a-licen%C3%A7a-apache-2-0?noredirect=1#comment155131_75904) e se houverem duas respostas que discordem eu não saberei qual é a correta. Como seria então?

Answer (score 11):

Apesar de concordar totalmente com a ótima [resposta do Luiz Vieira](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4113/12), acho que vale um pouco de contexto histórico sobre a situação e a filosofia por trás dessa parte específica da plataforma.

O Stack Overflow nasceu para solucionar um problema bem específico: não era possível encontrar respostas para dúvidas de programação de maneira *rápida* e *confiável*. Não era uma falta completa de lugares onde programadores podiam conversar ou tirar dúvidas, esses locais existiam mas falhavam em um, ou ambos, desses requerimentos.

No caso da *rapidez*, o caso mais óbvio eram os fóruns. Perguntas feitas lá eram debatidas incessantemente - o que não é necessariamente ruim - e qualquer tentativa de resposta era coletivamente construida aos poucos, tendendo a se perder em um mar de conversas transversais ou paralelas. Não era possível saber se o problema tinha sido completamente solucionado, ou onde estava a solução correta.

Quanto à *confiabilidade*, o problema era saber qual das várias respostas oferecidas era a melhor, se ela realmente solucionava o problema. Haviam outros sites de perguntas e respostas (a Microsoft tinha um no MSDN, eu acho) mas os votos funcionavam de maneira diferente, e outros usuários (no caso da MS, seus MVPs) podiam marcar respostas como corretas.

Dar a terceiros o poder de marcar respostas parece fazer sentido, tanto por justiça com quem escreveu uma resposta correta quanto em termos de organização do site. O problema é que isso fere diretamente a *confiabilidade* das respostas. Uma resposta aceita nos Stack Overflows automaticamente inspira confiança, porque necessariamente passou pelo crivo da única pessoa 100% capacitada para avaliá-la. Isso é algo fácil de desmerecer hoje, mas que fez muita diferença 7 anos atrás e também para qualquer usuário que conhece o site hoje.

Não há nenhuma maneira funcional de dar esse poder a terceiros sem automaticamente desvalorizar o significado da resposta aceita, não interessa quantos requerimentos sejam implementados. E o valor tácito das respostas aceitas, a confiança que elas inspiram, é parte muito importante do sucesso dos Stack Overflows.

Comment: Não sabia da parte histórica, agora ainda faz mais sentido para mim que continue como está. Eu não consigo entender os motivos de quem quer respostas aceites pela comunidade a não ser a pontuação. Não me parece que pudesse melhorar o site em nada, alias como tu disseste quase de certeza que iria piorar.

Comment: Esse último paragrafo está excelente. Tenho de treinar mais as minhas *skills* de argumentação.

Comment: Se o SOPT fosse um hotel, eu enquadraria a parte com o pequeno histórico das decisões (2º a 4º parágrafos) e iria pendurá-lo, logo ali, no hall de entrada. Seria definitivamente útil para muitas das conversas com os novos hóspedes a respeito das regras do hotel... :)

Comment: @Gabe, como ficam os casos em que a pergunta não seja um problema, mas uma dúvida em que o autor da pergunta realmente não sabe se a resposta é certa, por exemplo, fiz hoje [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75904/posso-vender-um-subproduto-de-um-produto-sob-a-licen%C3%A7a-apache-2-0?noredirect=1#comment155131_75904) e se houverem duas respostas que discordem usando argumentos válidos eu não saberei qual é a correta. Não acho que deveria dar o poder de aceite para terceiros, mas como ficam casos onde o AP "não tem poder" para decidir se a resposta é certa?

Answer (score 10):

Antes de mais nada, acho importante discutirmos também **o porquê** de um recurso como esse ser julgado como necessário. Não sei qual é a visão dos demais a respeito, mas eu creio que existam duas motivações principais pra cobrar cuidado na aceitação de perguntas:

1. As perguntas sem uma resposta marcada como aceita aparecem no site na seção "sem resposta" e por isso ficam em um estado "incompleto", quase como se o processo de construção daquele conteúdo não tivesse sido propriamente terminado.
2. A reputação de aceite não é devidamente recebida por uma resposta que alguém, além do AP original, julga como a melhor (geralmente, o autor da resposta).

Com essa forma de pensar, eu tendo a ser **contra** a implementação de qualquer recurso de votação ou obrigação na escolha da resposta aceita.

Primeiramente, quando uma pergunta tem respostas mas nenhuma é aceita, ou o AP simplesmente esqueceu de aceitar uma delas ou as respostas existentes não lhe são suficientemente boas e a pergunta realmente carece de mais atenção, *sob o seu ponto de vista*. Em ambos os casos, isso não significa que o conteúdo ali existente vai ser inútil para outras pessoas. Muitas vezes eu encontrei conteúdo em vários sites da rede Stack Exchange em que, dadas as especificidades do meu particular problema ou as minhas preferências pessoais, a resposta que mais me ajudou *não foi* a resposta a aceita. Por isso eu acredito que a marcação de uma resposta aceita serve apenas como um indicador adicional de que o AP (a pessoa que originalmente teve o problema ou a dúvida) realmente se sentiu satisfeito com tal resposta. A aceitação não garante que a resposta é canônica, única e suficiente para qualquer leitor, e o grande mérito do sistema de respostas é que é possível ter complementos e alternativas, enfim, conteúdo que realmente pode ser útil para explorar a solução de uma dúvida de forma *colaborativa*.

Ainda do ponto de vista da "completude" do processo, a interface do site no botão "Sem resposta" permite filtrar as perguntas que não têm *nenhuma resposta* das demais (que têm respostas, mas nenhuma aceita), e isso ajuda a entender que perguntas com respostas sem uma aceita não foram necessariamente abandonadas.

Em segundo lugar, a preocupação com reputação é natural e honesta, pois está dentro da regra do jogo. Acho que os respondentes têm o direito de sugerir polidamente ao AP o aceite das respostas via comentários quando julgarem-nas merecedoras. Da mesma forma, também é a regra do jogo que os APs não são obrigados a aceitar a resposta em momento algum. Isso lhes é sugerido, mas não demandado, até porque (como já amplamente argumentado) ninguém além do AP tem como saber se uma resposta foi totalmente satisfatória para ele.

Enfim, eu sou contra a implementação de um recurso para permitir à comunidade ou aos moderadores escolherem uma resposta como aceita simplesmente porque isso vai servir apenas para conceder reputação ao autor de uma resposta. Esse tipo de decisão não vai ser efetiva em melhorar o conteúdo porque a marca verdinha em uma resposta escolhida pela comunidade só vai indicar o que muitos votos já indicam: que essa resposta é bem avaliada pela comunidade, independentemente da opinião do AP.

Comment: Soubeste explicar duma forma excelente a minha forma de pensar. É mesmo isso.

Comment: É isso mesmo .!

Comment: Além do mais, se a resposta for boa mesmo – tipo aquelas suas :) –, ela vai ter muitos votos e +15 seriam irrelevantes em termos de rep ganha.

Comment: Excelente resposta

Comment: Eu disse que você deveria ter concorrido nas eleições, muito boa a resposta, me fez repensar, vou até apagar a minha resposta aqui nessa discussão

Answer (score 8):

Eu acredito que a pontuação das respostas já reflete a validade da resposta, e que no máximo, a moderação poderia aceitar respostas caso a pergunta tenha um determinado tempo com resposta (Exemplo 1 ano que fulano respondeu) e o fulano não acesse o soPT por aproximadamente o mesmo tempo ou em casos visíveis de o AP agradecer e não marcar.

Comment: Em caso nenhum outra pessoa que não o AP deve aceitar a resposta. Quer dizer eu tenho uma pergunta sem ter selecionado nenhuma resposta. Ausento-me um ano alguém escolhe por mim?!

Comment: @JorgeB. eu acho justo, mas claro que o AP teria que ser notificado, e ciente desta notificação tivesse o privilégio necessário para reverter, desmarcando a solução e fazendo suas considerações.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Justo em que sentido? Da reputação? Só se for. A reputação é um extra para apimentar o site, não é a principal função do site.

Comment: @JorgeB. acho justo limpar o SOPT das perguntas em abertas que tem uma possível solução e não tem um retorno do AP

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Limpar conteúdo que pode ajudar outras pessoas? Não, claro que não, nunca. Se a pergunta for boa e tiver respostas boas o que interessa se está uma delas marcada como certa? 
Se o AP marcar melhor, ficamos a saber qual a resposta que o ajudou. Mas se não marcar a informação está lá na mesma para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @JorgeB. fica inconclusivo se realmente ajudou o AP porque ele simplesmente não da mais retorno, isso ao meu ver é desanimador, uma pessoa se dedica a responder e não tem ao menos um retorno seja ele positivo ou negativo a respeito

Comment: Mas isso podemos encorajar os AP's a marcar as perguntas certas. Outra coisa é obrigar ou marcar por eles.

Comment: É necessário entender que o AP que tem reputação 1 e perguntou a um ano atrás e nunca mais logou, esse cara, na maioria dos casos, não vai voltar para aceitar a resposta. São essas situações que me refiro.

Comment: Não é uma obrigação, é um consenso que ocorre naturalmente por votos e decisões dos moderadores. Se uma resposta não for votada, ou se os moderadores não acharem que devem selecionar alguma, não será selecionada nenhuma ficando sem resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que eu já disse [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4100/7210) e pelos mesmos motivos [desta resposta do @LuizVieira](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4113/7210) não concordo com esse sistema. Mas imaginando que ele vai para a frente, a aceitação da pergunta dessa forma não deveria nunca dar pontuação.

Ainda querem implementar esse sistema se não der pontuação?

Sejam sinceros...

Comment: Eu aceitaria o sistema mesmo não dando a pontuação, já seria um passo na direção de **tentar** limpar as perguntas abandonadas pelo AP. Ou em vez de dar uma aceitação na resposta fosse para suspenso até o retorno do AP se pronunciar

Comment: "limpar as perguntas abandonadas pelo AP" não é política do site e espero que nunca seja... Isso já é outro assunto que não o acima mencionado. E suspender uma pergunta porque "não aceitou uma resposta" parece-me ainda mais grave. Ironizando "A sua pergunta foi suspensa porque ninguém soube responder convenientemente a ela"

Comment: melhor chat porque explanar no comentário fica difícil estou tentando usar poucas palavras mas com certeza não estamos se entendendo por minha falta, lhe aguardarei no chat então e tentarei mostrar o meu ponto de vista que com certeza não é esse que você replicou ai em cima

Comment: O importante é a pergunta não ter resposta. Eu não acho que precise dar pontos a quem selecionar a resposta certa, e acho que isso não faz sentido também. Ganham todos com uma resposta correta selecionada por consenso também. Ganho ponto quem recebeu o voto de consenso ou seja o AR

Comment: Sim​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Exatamente. Mas talvez a pergunta seja mais bem colocada se for: "Ainda faz sentido para a qualidade do conteúdo implementar esse sistema se não der pontuação?"

Answer (score 3):

A resposta com mais pontuação já fica em primeiro lugar, então o conteúdo fica disponível, sem problemas.

Com relação à reputação e recompensa pelo esforço de responder, porquê não se estipula que após X dias sem alteração, se uma pergunta não teve resposta marcada, e se há uma resposta com mais de Y votos, o autor da resposta recebe os pontos.

Esses pontos seriam revertidos, claro, se o AP marcar uma resposta (como acontece se ele tivesse marcado uma resposta e mudasse).

Pronto, o autor é recompensando, e ninguém precisa escolher uma resposta pelo AP.

Comment: O problema não são os pontos ao meu ver.