# O que ganha a comunidade em ter uma resposta aceite em cada pergunta?

Tags: debate, respostas, resposta-aceita

Tenho estado a seguir com alguma atenção o debate gerado pela pergunta ["Marcar resposta correta por consenso"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4089/2541).

Apesar de legitima, parece-me que, antes de se discutir a forma da sua implementação, se deve discutir se isso acrescenta valor ou não para a comunidade.

Como as resposta e/ou comentários a favor nenhum(a) justifica a razão para a sua implementação, fica a pergunta:

> O que  ganha a comunidade em ter uma resposta aceite em cada pergunta?

Comment: Acho que isto poderia ter sido discutido na própria pergunta, não? Entretanto eu penso que talvez realmente não seja algo necessário (acredito que você também pense assim)

Comment: Eu acho uma boa discussão. A outra pergunta é um pedido de novo recurso, e as respostas estão indo pelo caminho de propor como isso pode ser implementado. Eu ia postar lá uma resposta que não se posicionava em relação ao recurso, mas que debatia a questão. Agora pretendo postar aqui.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Se eu colocasse lá como comentário iria passar despercebida e não levaria o debate para o ponto que eu acho ser o importante.

Comment: @bfavaretto Foi isso mesmo que me levou a colocar esta pergunta.

Comment: Entendi, tem razão. Sobre a sua questão eu acho que não necessariamente "forçar" uma resposta correta seja algo útil, ou seja os votos positivos já fazem um trabalho semelhante e isto com certeza causaria conflito com o autor da pergunta, acaso ele aparece-se depois. Eu pessoalmente não vejo benefícios.

Comment: Nada, não ganha nada.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3117)

Comment: @Math Essa resposta vem de encontro aquilo que eu penso, ela apenas refere que é importante aceitar porque : "[...] deixa claro aos demais usuários que **seu problema** está resolvido, [...]. Ao mesmo tempo, **recompensa o autor** da melhor resposta por ter resolvido **seu problema**, isso pouco ou nada acrescenta ao propósito do site.

Comment: O debate é importante, entretanto estou dando -1 pois a parte do título que diz "**em cada pergunta**" parece querer desvirtuar a proposta de dar o poder de aceitação para a comunidade, fazendo parecer com que se torne obrigatório que toda pergunta tenha uma resposta aceita.

Comment: @Math mais uma vez percebeu mal. O que ele quer dizer é "Aceitar perguntas é assim tão importante para o propósito do site?"

Comment: @Math Não quero *desvirtuar* nada,  não é fácil incluir no título todo o sentido do que se quer perguntar, para isso serve o corpo.

Comment: @ramaral desculpa se pareceu ofensa o que eu disse (não foi minha intenção), mas eu acho que a proposta inicial do Delfino é de aceitar alguns casos, e não todos os casos.

Comment: Também acho que isso poderia ter sido discutido na própria pergunta.

Comment: Um item que não vejo comentado... Uma resposta é considerada duplicata de outra, mais antiga, somente se a mais antiga tem uma resposta satisfatória. Agora, quem define "resposta satisfatória", se o AP não marcar a resposta? Fechar duplicatas se julgarmos que uma resposta, não marcada, é satisfatória é pior que marcarmos, 'por consenso', uma resposta.

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2296/2541) à pergunta *"Só devo votar como duplicata as perguntas cujo duplicado já tem resposta?"*. Não existe isso de "resposta satisfatória", basta a pergunta ter uma resposta com pontuação positiva. Votar *"como duplicata*" e *"aceitar por consenso"* são coisas que não se podem comparar. A primeira tem a ver com a manutenção/moderação do site, a segunda tem, a meu ver, apenas com alguns *pontinhos de reputação* extra.

Comment: @RSinohara, apenas para chamar a sua atenção para o comentário anterior, esqueci de fazer referência a si.

Comment: Uma pergunta aceita, pode ser a resposta ideal para o seu problema específico, embora, existam respostas melhores não aceitas para a mesma pergunta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu vejo assim, uma pergunta pode ter "mais de uma resposta" correta, se o autor não selecionou nenhuma ou abandonou tudo isto não interfere na qualidade da(s) resposta(s) existente(s), isto apenas diz que para o autor da pergunta aquilo não resolveu ou ele realmente não entende o funcionamento de um Q&A.

Acho que os votos já refletem a opinião da comunidade de qual ou quais respostas são melhores e mesmo que uma resposta seja escolhida pelo autor não significa que aquela resposta seja a correta, já vi casos aqui que o autor escolheu uma resposta que nem mesmo era uma resposta, era mais um comentário.

Para a comunidade eu não vejo benefícios em ter a *"resposta correta"* por consenso, sendo que os votos já refletem a opinião da "qualidade" da resposta na maioria das vezes.

---

Sobre a [resposta do @SneepSNinjA](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4090/3635)

A principio soa como uma boa ideia a moderação (ou consenso) marcar a resposta "correta", mas eu vou discordar, pelo simples fato que hoje podemos ter uma resposta boa em uma pergunta e duas semanas (mês ou anos) depois pode aparecer uma nova resposta melhor ainda o que invalidaria o processo.

Sobre deletar perguntas antigas o @Math informou que existe tal sistema, acaso não haja pontuação positiva em nenhuma das postagens (foi o que eu entendi). Então penso eu que se existir um ponto positivo na pergunta ou na resposta, podemos dizer que isto já foi útil a alguém e que poderá a vir ser útil ou interessante para outras pessoas. E outro detalhe, temos uma ferramenta que automaticamente traz as perguntas antigas "não marcadas" como corretas para a página inicial (como se houve-se edição), é o "modificado pela comunidade", como explicado nestas respostas:

- [O que significa “modificada pela Comunidade”?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1953/3635)
- [Perguntas antigas podem ser postadas novamente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3969/3635)

---

Faço da [resposta do @Earendul a minha](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4102/3635)

> Acho que o simples e singelo fato de uma pessoa postar uma pergunta aqui já é uma contribuição, direta ou indiretamente, para a comunidade. O fato de ele não marcar uma resposta, ou sumir e nunca mais voltar, não tira a sua contribuição, afinal, é disso que vive esta comunidade.
>
> Acho que do jeito que está é a melhor maneira. Se o AP marcar alguma resposta como certa, ótimo, senão ótimo também, pois a pessoa já contribuiu por postar uma pergunta(vai que foi uma ótima pergunta!).

Comment: Faço da tua a minha resposta. Eu não me soube explicar bem, mas tu soubeste e muito bem.

Answer (score 13):

Eu não acho ruim que a pessoa que perguntou indique qual é a melhor resposta na opinião dela, a resposta que funcionou melhor pra ela. Acho bom, a marca verde na lateral dá um grau a mais de credibilidade à resposta, é um sinal de reconhecimento para com quem respondeu, e de respeito com quem perguntou, que tem o direito de indicar claramente a solução que resolveu o seu problema. É uma informação a mais que o leitor da pergunta e das respostas terá para avaliar qual seria a melhor solução para o seu próprio problema.

Até aqui estou concordando com o Victor (acho). Mas a maneira como esse recurso funciona – a resposta aceita vai para o topo, a não ser que seja de autoria de quem perguntou – é discutível. Se é verdade que a opinião do autor da pergunta e a opinião da comunidade geralmente coincidem, quando elas divergem o sistema dá mais peso à opinião do indivíduo do que à opinião da comunidade.

Em termos gerais, em quem o visitante que chega do Google deveria poder confiar mais: em quem fez uma pergunta, aceitou uma resposta e deu-se por satisfeito, ou no conjunto de pessoas que avaliaram as respostas todas ao longo do tempo? Eu acho que o sistema está pendendo para o lado errado aqui ao *sempre* dar mais destaque à resposta aceita. Mesmo assim, mudar isso não me parece algo que valha a pena, já que se aplica à minoria dos casos em que o AP e a comunidade discordam.

---

**UPDATE 2015-08-27**

Surgiu recentemente no MSE uma proposta que resolve parcialmente o problema da discordância entre a resposta escolhida pelo autor da pergunta e a mais votada pela comunidade: [Let's move some negatively scored answers from the top spot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264045). A sugestão é que respostas aceitas com pontuação de `-3` ou inferior deixem de ir para o topo. Acho uma boa ideia.

---

Estou chamando atenção a esse detalhe porque acho que ele está por trás de algo muito mais relevante, uma contradição que existe em todas as comunidades da Stack Exchange, e fica mais acentuada conforme esses sites crescem, principalmente em movimento diário.

Nós vivemos em um frágil equilíbrio entre tentar atender aos interesses de indivíduos e de coletividades. Os indivíduos somos todos os usuários do site, dos mais assíduos, com maior pontuação, aos não registrados que apenas consomem o conteúdo que encontram pelos mecanismos de busca. As coletividades (estou evitando a expressão "a comunidade") são os grupos de pessoas com uma atuação mais constante no site. Cada indivíduo tem suas próprias opiniões, mas "a comunidade" e seus subgrupos tendem a opiniões mais negociadas, em que cada indivíduo abre mão de parte de suas opiniões pessoais em prol de um consenso coletivo.

Há quem pense que os dois objetivos (atender aos indivíduos e ao coletivo) são mutuamente exclusivos, e que é necessário escolher um deles. E há quem pense que é a justamente a tensão entre eles, constantemente equacionada, que fará o site "dar certo".

Não pretendo aqui chegar a nenhuma conclusão definitiva. Minha intenção nesta segunda parte da resposta foi compartilhar uma reflexão que venho construindo há um tempo, e a pergunta do @ramaral me levou novamente ao assunto.

Comment: A reflexão é muito interessante. A conclusão continua complicada. Até me apetece apagar a minha resposta, mas deixo ficar para me lembrar que há formas e formas de demonstrar um ponto de vista e a minha se calhar não foi a mais amigável, digamos. É por isso que és moderador deste site. Parabéns :)

Comment: Confesso que fiquei um pouco desiludido, esperava uma resposta mais assertiva da sua parte.

Comment: @ramaral Eu entendo, minha resposta foge ao que foi perguntado. Mas pensei que minha posição sobre o seu questionamento estivesse clara: acho a aceitação é um recurso importante, implementado de maneira incoerente; e que tal incoerência, entretanto, pode ser mantida, já que só ocorre numa minoria das perguntas, e os sites da SE têm funcionado bem assim mesmo.

Comment: @ramaral Dei uma mexida na minha resposta, espero que agora minha posição esteja mais clara.

Comment: É contra apenas essa questão de destacar com o verde e a resposta melhor pontuada acabar ficando abaixo dela( é isso mesmo? ). Se alterar para que a com maior numero de votos for a top e a aceite for a próxima ao meu ver não mudaria muita coisa

Answer (score 11):

Ok, posso fazer a pergunta um pouco mais a fundo: **Porque nós, mesmo os usuários experientes, devemos aceitar respostas em nossas perguntas sem que seja apenas para contar pontos de reputação?**

Essa é uma pergunta um tanto retórica e eu tenho uma resposta minha mais abaixo, mas gostaria de saber também o que os outros acham.

No link do [*tour*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) **não** explica **porquê** fazer isso, apenas diz o que é e o que significa:

> A pessoa que perguntou pode marcar uma resposta como "aceita".
>
> A aceitação não significa que seja a melhor resposta, apenas significa que foi útil para a pessoa que perguntou.

Outras perguntas retóricas:

**E mesmo que nós usuários experientes façamos isso, porque os novatos deveriam também fazer?**

**Ou será que isso é um apenas um mecanismo para ficar contando pontos de reputação, acumular medalhas e destravar privilégios?**

**Se já posso votar a favor, porque o aceite é necessário?**

Bem, já temos quatro perguntas retóricas aqui. Agora vou respondê-las com a minha opinião.

**Aceitar uma resposta é um sinal de RECONHECIMENTO**, e serve para:

- Sinalizar para os demais usuários que o problema está resolvido e que você está satisfeito com a solução.
- Premiar a pessoa que deu a resposta que te ajudou a solucionar o seu problema.

Ok, mas daí você poderia dizer: Um comentário do tipo "obrigado" e um voto a favor poderia ter o mesmo efeito. Mas a questão vai muito além de quem perguntou e quem respondeu: **Quando eu procuro pela solução de um problema no Google e venho parar no StackOverflow, eu gostaria logo de ver qual que é a resposta aceita que provavelmente irá solucionar o meu problema.** E só se essa resposta não servir é que vou olhar as outras. No entanto, se não houver uma resposta aceita, já me ligo que talvez o problema nunca tenha sido solucionado e que as respostas possivelmente estão erradas ou solucionam o problema apenas parcialmente.

O fato de haver uma resposta aceita na pergunta que achei no Google, me faz economizar tempo e me tornar mais produtivo, pois ela me dá uma dica de qual a resposta mais importante, aumentando a taxa de sinal/ruído que é exatamente o diferencial do StackOverflow. Ok, é verdade que nem sempre a resposta aceita é a melhor ou a que de fato resolve o problema, mas no geral o número de vezes que a resposta aceita é a melhor é bem maior do que o número de vezes em que ela não é, e isso melhora a minha produtividade. E como já expliquei no parágrafo anterior, só quando a resposta aceita não me parece satisfatória é que eu acho melhor dar uma olhada nas demais respostas.

Mas, e o usuário que não se importa em aceitar? Bem, neste caso o fato de que ele escolheu ser preguiçoso e não se importar com as regras básicas do funcionamento da comunidade (se é que um dia ele já pensou nisso), me faz perder muito tempo tendo que ler diversas respostas e muitos comentários. Além disso, ele está deixando de contribuir com o crescimento da comunidade que o ajudou a solucionar o seu problema e não dando reconhecimento a quem o ajudou, o que eu interpreto como sendo uma atitude egoísta ou no mínimo preguiçosa.

É verdade que sempre tem aquele usuário que se cadastrou a pouco tempo e que só fez uma ou duas perguntas e provavelmente não sabe como o site funciona (e são muuuitos) e que por isso, ele não aceita a resposta porque nem sabe o que seria isso. Esse caso é perfeitamente compreensível e perdoável. Mas quando o usuário já fez umas 10 perguntas, já está aqui há algum tempo e já acumulou alguns pontinhos de reputação e mesmo assim parece estar se lixando, ele começa a merecer alguns dos meus raríssimos downvotes!

Comment: concordo contigo +1

Comment: Concordo com quase tudo. Mas coloco ênfase na passagem *"[...] pois ela me dá uma dica de qual a resposta mais importante (para o AP) [...]"*, pra argumentar que eu acho um exagero dizer que quem não aceita respostas está deixando de contribuir com o crescimento da comunidade. É verdade que a aceitação é uma boa *indicação* e uma devida recompensa, mas a criação de conteúdo é o verdadeiro objetivo do site. Usuários que nunca aceitam respostas mas ainda assim produzem perguntas que geram conteúdo, são tão relevantes como quem aceita tudo.

Comment: Além disso, eu sou da opinião de que educação (insistir em explicar o funcionamento *ideal*) é mais efetiva em estimular certos comportamentos em uma comunidade do que a penalização dos membros. Principalmente quando os motivos da penalização lhes são ainda menos claros do que os benefícios do comportamento que idealizamos pra eles. :)

Answer (score 8):

**A comunidade já ganhou.**

Acho que o simples e singelo fato de uma pessoa postar uma pergunta aqui já é uma contribuição, direta ou indiretamente, para a comunidade. O fato de ele não marcar uma resposta, ou sumir e nunca mais voltar, não tira a sua contribuição, afinal, é disso que vive esta comunidade.

Acho que do jeito que está é a melhor maneira. Se o AP marcar alguma resposta como certa, ótimo, senão ótimo também, pois a pessoa já contribuiu por postar uma pergunta(vai que foi uma ótima pergunta!).

Comment: Afinal é este o propósito do site não é?

Comment: Esta merecia o visto ✓ :P

Comment: Concordo contigo +1

Comment: Eu descordo, acho fundamental destacar a melhor resposta por consenso, isso valoriza as respostas, além da pontuação destacando-a como sendo correta também.

Comment: O ✓ só serve para o AP indicar o seguinte: "Sua resposta foi útil. Obrigado". E, você mesmo já disse como destacar a melhor resposta por consenso.

Comment: @JorgeB. Será que eu sou o único que vê uma situação um tanto irônica a respeito do seu comentário "Esta merecia o visto ✓ :P"?

Comment: @VictorSafusa ainda bem que alguém percebeu ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Agora fiquei confuso! Concordas ou não com o que é dito nesta resposta?

Comment: @ramaral Sim, concordo com esta resposta, é a melhor resposta esta. Porquê?

Comment: @JorgeB. Por causa da *ironia* a que o VictorStafusa se referia.

Comment: @ramaral A ironia é eu ter dito que esta resposta devia ser aceite, quando estou contra as pessoas decidirem respostas aceites ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Entendi. No entanto qualquer um tem o direito de achar qual resposta devia ser aceite não pode ter é o direito de aceitá-la por mim.

Comment: @ramaral exatamente isso.

Answer (score 4):

### 1) O modelo do site

O modelo do site diz:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se a pessoa diz: "Muito obrigado meu chapa! Funcionou belezinha! Tchau...", significa que a resposta foi útil para a pessoa que perguntou, só que ela não se deu ao trabalho de entender como que funciona a comunidade e ela informou que a resposta foi útil do jeito que ela está acostumada a dizer nos fóruns, através de um comentário.

Os sites da rede SE são todos colaborativos, podemos editar outras publicações, podemos excluí-las, fechá-las, temos quase que *total controle* sobre as publicações de todo mundo no site da rede, entretanto, até hoje, **a única** coisa que não podemos fazer é justamente concluir o tópico.

Mas se a comunidade se baseia justamente no princípio da colaboratividade, o que que a conclusão de um tópico tem de tão especial que ele é a única etapa de um processo de uma pergunta que não é de propriedade da comunidade, e sim de propriedade de um único indivíduo?

### 2) Recompensa

Um "obrigado" é legal, mas comentários são cidadãos de segunda classe dentro da cultura da Stack Exchange. A resposta ganha muito mais destaque se tiver uma marcação em formato de "V", verde e bem grande ao lado dela, do que um "obrigado" no 6º comentário da resposta, que só é visível após clicar em "mostrar mais comentários".

### 3) Casos específicos

A ideia **não** é fazer com que todas as perguntas com respostas tenham uma marcada como correto, estamos falando de casos óbvios que o problema já foi solucionado entretanto faltou a cereja em cima do bolo: a marcação de aceite.

### 4) Exemplos

Respostas que poderiam ter sido marcadas como "concluídas", mas não estão:

#### 4.1) [Movimentação de forms c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71591/3117)

> valeu meu querido , deu certo ! muito obrigado !!! –  Rennan 28/06 às 20:51

---

#### 4.2) [Array com informações de um banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58482/3117)

> Obrigado fiz dessa forma deu certo –  Clayton Eduardo Mergulhão 18/05 às 16:31

---

#### 4.3) [Código imprime duas vezes mas deveria imprimir somente uma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34156/3117)

> Obrigado resolveu! :D poderia me dar uma breve explicação sobre essa diferença de nextLine para next? –  Ygor Ramos 28/09/14 às 4:11

Esse chegou a inclusive a escrever "(RESOLVIDO)" no título da pergunta, vejam no histórico de edições.

---

#### 4.4) [converter uma string em vb.net - convert.toDouble](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57086/3117)

> Vivendo e aprendendo. Muito Obrigado. Só pra deixar registrado precisa importar também -> Imports System.Globalization. Valeu –  David Coopermine 6/04 às 18:05

---

PS: Não consegui caçar muitos casos assim pois ainda não me entendo muito bem com o [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

### 5) Mais uma vez

A ideia **não é aceitar todas as perguntas que tem respostas mas nenhumas delas está marcada como aceita**, ok?

Comment: Julgo que não respondeu à pergunta. A única justificação que encontro na sua resposta é a recompensa e essa é só para o autor da resposta e não para a comunidade.

Comment: "**pode** ser marcada como aceita"

Comment: Eu sinceramente atualmente prefiro um obrigado mesmo ;)

Comment: @Math define quais são os casos óbvios e quais não são.

Comment: @JorgeB. "obrigado" é coisa de fórum

Comment: @Math eu sei por isso pus o sorriso.

Comment: Se ter as respostas resolvidas e de fácil percepção que aquela resposta está correta não é ajuda a comunidade, então não sei o que é.

Comment: @JorgeB. alguns são óbvios, como os que eu listei no item 4, alguns são nebulosos e se não houver consenso da comunidade é melhor deixar desmarcado mesmo

Comment: @Math o problema é mesmo esse. Quem decide o que é óbvio e o que não é.

Comment: Os mesmos que decidem que uma pergunta pode ser fechada ou suspensa... os usuários

Comment: @ramaral editei e pergunta, realmente eu tinha fugido um pouco do tópico

Comment: Não é a mesma coisa. Não obrigamos ninguém a votar positivamente na pergunta se for boa. Verificamos apenas se a pergunta tem qualidade para estar no site. Assim como verificamos também nas respostas. Marcar a pergunta como certa é obrigar alguém a aceitar uma das respostas que obteve. Nada tem a ver uma coisa com a outra.

Comment: "só que ela não se deu ao trabalho de entender como que funciona a comunidade e ela informou que a resposta foi útil do jeito que ela está acostumada a dizer nos fóruns, através de um comentário." como você sabe isso? Eu posso simplesmente não querer marcar nenhuma resposta na mesma apesar de ter dito isso.

Comment: @JorgeB. eu também tenho perguntas em aberto que eu não quero que ninguém chegue e aceite por mim, eu só gostaria de corrigir casos de que o AP está acostumado com o sistema de fórum e edita a pergunta para escrever "resolvido" no título, ou que fala "obrigado" nos comentários

Comment: @Math mas depois de teres o sistema aberto o que irá acontecer é que toda a gente quer respostas aceites, e vão colocar em analise.

Comment: Esse problema deve ser resolvido colocando um comentário do tipo: *Ainda bem que pude ajudar e bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) a forma de proceder quando uma resposta te foi útil.*

Comment: E mesmo nesses casos não consigo achar bem, porque se está a passar por cima da vontade (ou não) da pessoa.

Comment: @JorgeB. daí já é outro caso, a primeira questão é: "queremos que a comunidade tenha o poder de aceitar respostas pelos outros?", depois verificamos como evitar abusos

Comment: @Math mas eu acho que é sempre um abuso marcar uma resposta como aceite por outra pessoa. É como alterar o código duma pergunta ou duma resposta. É alterar a vontade da pessoa.

Comment: @JorgeB. não estou falando de alterar a vontade da pessoa, to falando de pessoas que não sabem usar o site.

Comment: @Math mais uma vez como você sabe se são ou não pessoas que não sabem usar o site? Posso ser só eu sendo egoista. Conheço alguns casos de pessoas usam o site diariamente e nunca marcam respostas como aceites. Inclusive minhas, mas é a vontade deles. E se você por acaso acha que ele não sabe usar o site e marca uma resposta como aceite?

Comment: @JorgeB. existem casos e casos. Alguns são nebulosos e é provável que não haja consenso, nesses casos é melhor deixar sem marcar mesmo.

Comment: Math e @JorgeB. Acho que temos que organizar melhor o debate, pois temos várias sugestões diferentes, mas a maioria está enxergando apenas duas possibilidades, o que leva a um debate desorganizado. Eu vejo pelo menos 4 possibilidades. 1) Deixar como está. 2) O usuário que fez muitas perguntas sem aceitar respostas é forçado a escolher uma resposta para cada pergunta aonde não aceitou nenhuma resposta, ou então a declarar de alguma forma que nenhuma das respostas serviu antes de poder fazer mais perguntas. [continua no comentário abaixo...]

Comment: [continuando o comentário acima...] 3) Os moderadores e usuários de alta reputação podem marcar como aceita uma resposta aonde o autor da pergunta colocou um comentário do tipo "Valeu, obrigado. Funcionou belezinha", e na dúvida deixa-se como está. 4) Se depois de algum tempo, não houver resposta marcada como correta, a comunidade elege uma. ---- Além disso, cada uma dessas alternativas pode ser implementada de formas diferentes. Eu pessoalmente prefiro a alternativa 2, mas também sou a favor da 3. Sou contra a 1 e a 4.

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu sou a favor da 3, principalmente no que diz "na dúvida deixa-se como está". Posso aceitar a 1, apesar de preferir a 3. E sou contra a 2 e a 4.

Comment: Sou a favor da 1, cada um decide/aprende se quer aceitar ou não uma resposta. Não se esqueçam que me parece que a SE vai manter a 1

Comment: Não entendo que, depois de ler o que está escrito lá no quadradinho em cima, você(Math) continue a achar que o *"aceite"* é que define a boa/melhor resposta. A comunidade já participa na escolha da *"melhor"* quando vota nas respostas.

Comment: Também não sei onde você foi buscar a ideia de que aquela frase, lá no quadradinho, define o modelo do site.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Você fala em 4 alternativas, vou só comentar aquelas com que você concorda. 2) - "[...]sem aceitar respostas é **forçado** a escolher [...] ou então a **declarar de alguma forma** [...] antes de **poder fazer mais perguntas**.". Quer tornar o site numa ditadura? Ou implementar um regime totalitário? 3) - "Os moderadores e usuários de alta reputação podem marcar como aceita uma resposta ...". Em que ***"alta reputação"*** e ser **moderador** qualifica alguém para poder saber qual é a melhor resposta em assuntos que não dominam?

Comment: @ramaral Você está exagerando. Pois eu poderia então argumentar que já é uma ditadura aristocrática aonde um pequeno número de usuários pode fechar as questões dos demais. Isso poderia ser alguma coisa do tipo uma tela com "Ei, antes de postar uma nova pergunta, aceite as respostas nas suas perguntas já existentes", com um botão do tipo "Nenhuma resposta me satisfez até agora" ou "Não sei" em cada uma dessas perguntas. Desculpa, mas não consigo ver como isso torna o site um regime totalitário, pois se o usuário quiser deixar a pergunta sem resposta aceita, ele ainda consegue fazer isso.

Comment: @ramaral Quanto a "alta reputação" e moderador, eu poderia argumentar porque que estes mesmos podem sair fechando perguntas em assuntos que supostamente não dominam? O que eu propus é apenas no caso aonde "**sem dúvida**" e "**inequivocadamente**" a resposta satisfez o autor da pergunta, que deixou um comentário do tipo "valeu, funcionou direito". E "**em caso de isso ser incerto**" então **deixar-se-ia como está**.

Comment: @VictorStafusa As duas coisas não são comparáveis, para fechar questões, na maioria dos casos, não é preciso ter conhecimento sobre o assunto tratado mas sim conhecer as regras estabelecidas pelo site. O numero de usuários que podem sinalizar(>15) ou fechar(>3000) não é assim tão pequeno. Pequeno é o numero de *moderadores e usuários de alta reputação*

Comment: @ramaral Bem, quando há um comentário do tipo "Cara, muito obrigado, funcionou direitinho, valeu, tchau", eu não preciso entender absolutamente nada sobre a pergunta ou sobre a resposta para ver que aquela resposta deveria ter sido aceita. Já em perguntas que eu não me sinto capaz de dar opinião na fila de análise de fechamento, eu clico em "Pular". Além disso o termo "alta reputação" de fato não é bem definido. Poderia ser reputação >= 10000 que são bem poucos. Ou talvez reputação >= 3000 seria melhor. Não sei qual seria o limiar ideal, e eu nem queria entrar nesse nível de detalhe.

Comment: Eu discordo que aceitar uma resposta seja equivalente a "concluir o tópico". As perguntas aqui estão eternamente em aberto, sempre pode aparecer uma resposta melhor, mesmo que isso seja pouco provável. A aceitação é simplesmente a marca de que tal resposta serviu para o AP. E, como eu disse na minha resposta, isso tem um peso exagerado ao levar a resposta para o topo da lista, quando não condiz com a opinião da comunidade.

Comment: @bfavaretto nem sempre. Eu tenho este caso http://stackoverflow.com/a/30466790/1817673 em que passado dois anos mudei a resposta porquê apareceu uma resposta melhor que eu achei ser a mais correta e que me resolveu o problema. Acho que ela deve estar em primeiro apesar da outra ser a mais votada (também mais antiga)

Comment: @VictorStafusa o que tu e o Math não entendem é que fechar perguntas por elas não estarem dentro das regras do site nada tem a ver com decidir qual a melhor resposta pelos outros. Eu mesmo já comentei "Obrigado esta resposta me ajudou." e depois não aceito nenhuma porque não acho que nenhuma responda completamente a minha pergunta.

Comment: E como eu outros o farão mesmo sendo novatos no site. Como dá para saber? Não chega um comentário a dizer para aceitar uma resposta se alguma ajudou? Eu próprio tenho uma resposta em que o utilizador disse que resolveu o problema, mas ele não quis marcar nenhuma. Está no direito dele.

Comment: @JorgeB. Por isso que sou a favor do mecanismo 2. Você não quer aceitar nenhuma resposta? Clica em um botão escrito "Eu não quero aceitar nenhuma resposta" e segue em frente. Se depois você mudar de ideia, vai lá e aceita uma resposta. Se depois quiser "desaceitar" a resposta, vai lá e clica no botão de novo. Na minha visão, essa solução é simples, deixaria todos contentes e resolveria o problema.

Comment: @VictorStafusa isso iria criar ainda mais atritos entre as pessoas. Agora sou obrigado a depois de fazer uma pergunta fazer mais alguma coisa? A ideia dum site de Q&A é eu poder fazer uma pergunta e nunca mais querer saber dela, se ela for boa, há de ficar muitos anos no site e pouco importa se marquei como certa alguma resposta. Muito menos se marquei como "Eu não quero aceitar nenhuma resposta". Nunca mais ninguém no site me respondia a uma pergunta se eu fizesse isso.

Comment: @JorgeB. "A ideia dum site de Q&A é eu poder fazer uma pergunta e nunca mais querer saber dela" - Não, a ideia não é essa. Se você fez uma pergunta é porque você deve ter interesse em respostas. Não há sentido fazer perguntas se você não quiser obter respostas. Se não há resposta aceita, posso pensar em responder, e não gostaria de fazer isso em vão. Se já há uma resposta aceita, raramente tenho algum motivo para colocar mais outra resposta. E você pode trocar "Eu não quero aceitar nenhuma resposta" por "Ainda não estou satisfeito com as respostas".

Comment: @VictorStafusa de qualquer forma nem sequer é esse o ponto. O ponto está na obrigatoriedade de fazer coisas. Vê a [resposta do Luiz](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4113/7210) que explica bem a minha linha de pensamento. Que aqui já estamos a entrar por caminhos que nada tem a ver com a aceitação de respostas.

Comment: Ah e eu queria dizer "e poderia nunca mais querer saber dela". Isto porque tu fazes uma pergunta e vês respostas e não marcas nenhuma, mas até te ajudaram. E depois nunca mais queres saber dela e tas no teu direito. Agora vir alguém e marcar uma dessas respostas por ti está até a ludibriar quem vem ver a pergunta achando que aquela resposta ajudou o AP.

Comment: @JorgeB. Por isso que essa marcação seria só no caso aonde não haveria a menor dúvida sobre isso, aonde há um comentário do tipo "muito obrigado, funcionou direitinho, tchau". E esses casos são uma minoria. Os casos aonde o AP simplesmente sumiu ou não falou nada que seja conclusivo, não dá para se marcar qualquer resposta como aceita.

Comment: E como garantes que seria só nesses casos @VictorStafusa?

Comment: @JorgeB. Bem, como esses casos são raros, talvez seja algo que só moderadores poderiam fazer. Se os moderadores errarem, daí a situação fica difícil e tem que ser debatido no meta. Penso que talvez usuários de alta reputação poderiam fazer isso também por meio de uma votação (provavelmente requerendo unanimidade, exceto se houver voto de um moderador), mas talvez seria mais simples e mais seguro se fosse algo só para moderadores mesmo. Enfim, o objetivo aqui é corrigir um erro, e não passar por cima da vontade de ninguém.

Answer (score 0):

### Nada, não ganha nada.

Não ganha nada em ter respostas aceites escolhidas pela comunidade. As respostas devem ser aceites ou não pelo AP.

Expliquem me lá para que precisamos desta nova *feature*?

Para absolutamente nada. Eu até tenho algumas perguntas sem resposta selecionada como certa e quero mantê-las assim. Devem haver muitos como eu. Até aparecer uma resposta que eu ache que deva colocar como certa.

Para que precisamos de marcar respostas como certas no caso de o AP não marcar? Em que é que isso nos vai ajudar?

São estas perguntas que eu não consigo responder de forma positiva.

Comment: "Expliquem me lá para que precisamos disto?" Foi exactamente isso que pensei quando vi a [outra](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4089/2541) pergunta.

Comment: Se não ganha absolutamente nada, então poderíamos tirar o aceite de uma vez por todas, não? Se você dissesse que o esforço não compensa os benefícios, pois eles seriam ínfimos visto o percentual de casos assim, eu poderia até concordar, mas dizer que não ganha nada, nada, seria o mesmo que dizer que o modelo do site está errado. -1

Comment: @Math não percebeste o que eu quis dizer com certeza. Eu estou a falar no caso em particular de aceitar repostas alheias. Isso sim é dizer que o modelo do site está errado.

Comment: Você até o momento fez 43 perguntas no site principal (a menos que haja mais algumas deletadas, não sei se há, mas não vem ao caso). Em 35 dessas perguntas você aceitou uma resposta, em 7 você não aceitou e 1 ainda não tem nenhuma resposta. Mas, me diga, nessas 35 perguntas, que sem dúvida são a maioria, porque você aceitou uma resposta nelas? Apenas pela reputação? Apenas porque isso é o que todo mundo faz e por isso você fez também? Ou será que houve um motivo melhor?

Comment: @VictorSafusa eu não sou contra o aceitar respostas, sou é contra a comunidade aceita las em vez dos AP. Que é o que está em discussão.

Comment: @JorgeB. Então, na sua opinião, qual é a finalidade de aceitar-se respostas? E quando for me responder, digite meu nome corretamente após o "@", caso contrário eu não sou notificado.

Comment: @VictorStafusa estava no mobile, nem reparei, desculpa. A finalidade de se aceitar respostas é "eu resolvi o meu problema com esta resposta". Mas, por exemplo, alguém marcar por mim uma resposta que eu deixei propositadamente sem aceitar só porque estive muito tempo sem vir cá retira essa finalidade que eu assumi acima.

Comment: @Math, acho que o que o Jorge quis dizer é que não se ganha nada em ter respostas aceitas *pela comunidade*. Isso não quer dizer que o modelo do site está errado. Pelo contrário! O modelo do site está totalmente certo, porque só o AP pode aceitar respostas! Dá-se muito valor para o aceite, mas ele é (do ponto de vista de um novo leitor) só uma indicação a mais de que aquela resposta foi satisfatória para ao menos uma pessoa (o autor original da pergunta).

Comment: @Math Fazer a comunidade fornecer essa indicação é não apenas redundante (porque a indicação da opinião comunitária já está nos votos) como desvirtua o modelo e cria mais um ônus no trabalho (agora, além de votar em respostas também tenho que votar em respostas aceitas).

Comment: @LuizVieira é isso mesmo.

Comment: Concordo 100% contigo! Aceitei a resposta do @Guilherme Nascimento porque ela justifica o **"Nada, não ganha nada."**

Answer (score 0):

O que a comunidade ganha se uma pergunta (A) tem uma resposta marcada?

Considerando que A tem uma resposta correta e aceitável, mas que não foi marcada como tal (e nenhuma outra o foi).

Bom, acho que reconhecimento, recompensa e incentivo para quem respondeu vale, mas a **pequena porcentagem** de perguntas 'abandonadas' faz com que a falta destes seja de pouco efeito.

Agora, uma pergunta só está **completa com uma resposta**. Assim, uma duplicata de A só pode ser fechada se A tem uma resposta. Alias, se uma pergunta B, posterior, duplicar A, mas obtiver uma resposta antes de A, **é A quem deve ser fechada**.

Concordo com a premissa que é complicado alguém definir uma resposta para uma pergunta que não é sua. Mas ao **fechar B** por duplicar A, não estamos também **decidindo que A possui uma resposta**? E não é mais grave que passar por cima de um AP que abandonou a pergunta?

Ou seja, a comunidade ganha porque a pergunta fica **completa**.

Comment: Não, não é nada mais grave, nem tem gravidade alguma. Uma pergunta fechada por ser duplicata pode ser reaberta. Ela não é eliminada do site, fica "lincada" à outra. Se a primeira pergunta não tiver uma resposta que satisfaça o autor da segunda ele pode editá-la, explicando isso. Depois de fechada alguém que queira responder pode fazê-lo na primeira pergunta. Esta são algumas razões, deve haver mais, para que a sua preocupação não tenha fundamento.

Comment: Se fechamos B por duplicar A, é porque A tem *pelo menos* uma resposta. Se não tiver nenhuma, o sistema nem deixa fechar.

Comment: E se essa resposta não for aceitável?