# Como e quem pode marcar uma pergunta com a tag pendente no final?

Tags: suporte, tags, sinalização

Eu veja muitas pessoas que confirmam que tal resposta é boa, só que não marcam a resposta como escolhida, e a pergunta fica aberta no ar por um longo tempo... muitas vezes a resposta está até no comentário, e ninguém coloca uma resposta. Eu gostaria de saber como funciona esse procedimento, como marcar uma pergunta como [pendente].

Comment: Só o OP pode marcar alguma resposta como aceita(sinal verde). Uma pergunta é marcada como pendente quando leva 5 votos de fechamento. Usuários com 3k podem votar para fechar perguntas.

Comment: Ok. Muito obrigado por sanar minha dúvida!

Comment: Eu não entendi a relação das perguntas "pendentes" com perguntas sem "respostas aceitas".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento se refere ao comentário do rray, ou a pergunta mesmo?

Comment: O status fica [pendente] nos primeiros 7 dias depois de fechada, para tentar passar a ideia de que a pergunta tem salvação. O status muda para [fechada] se ela permanecer [pendente] por 7 dias, para passar a ideia que já deu o tempo de mudá-la e provavelmente ela não receberá mais atenção. Mas em todos os casos ela pode ser melhorada e votada para reabrir.

Comment: O OP as vezes some ou resolve a questão e não volta mais, acontece. Tem um discussão sobre a comunidade aceitar uma reposta, se tiver interesse, [Marcar resposta correta por consenso](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4089/91)

Comment: @Math me refiro ao AP começar a postagem com problemas de perguntas sem resposta marcada como correta e terminar perguntando como marcar como `[pendente]`, ao meu ver uma pergunta sem resposta selecionando não é algo que entra na lista de pendentes/fechadas como esta no link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Ah tá, pq eu editei o comentário do @rray pois não tava claro para mim a princípio, rs

Comment: Relacionado [O que ganha a comunidade em ter uma resposta aceite em cada pergunta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4097/3635) ???

Comment: E como marca uma pergunta sem respostas aceitas por muito tempo, ela fica a berta e abandonada simplesmente?

Comment: @IvanFerrer então você se refere a marcar perguntas sem resposta como `[pendente]`? Perguntas só podem ser marcadas por estes motivos http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions e requer pontuação para isto ou flag.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, @GuilhermeNascimento, vou ler tudo.

Comment: @Math então parece que ele não havia mesmo entendido o sentido de `[pendente]` e achou que uso também valeria para situações como "perguntas abandonadas" eu formulei uma resposta :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, tb acho que foi isso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro vou começar dizendo que o autor não é obrigado a escolher uma resposta e mesmo escolhendo uma resposta, isto não quer dizer que ela é a melhor, como foi discutido aqui:

- [O que ganha a comunidade em ter uma resposta aceite em cada pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4097/3635)

Não vejo porque marcar uma pergunta como `[pendente]` pelo autor não ter selecionando uma resposta, as unicas perguntas que podem ser marcadas como pendentes são as que se encontram na situação citada aqui:

- [O que significa se uma pergunta está "encerrada" ou "em suspenso"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), são problemas do tipo:

  - duplicada
  - descontextualizada (fora do escopo)
  - não está claro o que você está perguntando
  - muito ampla

Se você tem 3k ou mais de rep você pode votar para fechar, abaixo de cada pergunta existe o link fechar e sinalizar:

<kbd>[image: Como fechar]</kbd>

São necessários cinco pessoas votarem pra ficar pendente. Se ainda não tem 3k de rep então pode sinalizar (flag).

### Conclusão

- A pergunta não precisa ter resposta marcada
- Muitas vezes o autor pode até marcar a resposta como correta, mas existe resposta melhor na própria pergunta
- Algumas vezes o autor esquece ou não sabe usar o site corretamente

Neste ultimo caso, recomendo você comentar na pergunta orientando o AP assim:

> Se uma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema, então marque-a como correta, se não sabe fazer isto veja o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), recomendo que leia este link: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635)

Eu geralmente faço isto em várias perguntas, até as que eu não respondi, ontem mesmo vi uma pergunta que tinha uma ótima resposta, o AP até agradeceu o autor da resposta, mas não marcou então eu comentei algo parecido com o exemplo.

> **Nota:** Muitas perguntas boas ficam sem respostas por um bom tempo e podem um dia receber uma resposta (ou não) – @Math

Comment: Acho que poderia lembrar (sem querer abusar da sua boa vontade, rs) que muitas perguntas boas ficam sem respostas por um bom tempo, e podem um dia receber ou uma resposta (ou não).

Comment: Boa resposta, melhor do que esperava.

Comment: @Math Editei, realmente, fica tranquilo gosto muito de participar e colaborar aqui no "meta" :)